# Multidimensional array of texture in Unity3d

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have some `textures` those i need to show in diffrent `scrollviews` dynamically.
for naming convention i am using below approach
**texturename24**
texturename - This prefix is associated with every texture.
2- This represents a particular category of texture i.e. dot. stripes , etc.
4 - This is for serial number of texture

with below lines of code i am fetching `textures` from resource folder
    var textures : Object[];
    textures = Resources.LoadAll("TextureFolder");

i need to make array for every pattern suppose `texturename00,01,02,03` should be in one array and `texturename10,11,12,13` should be other array, here i need to crate dynamic array on the basis of  patterns count.

Comment: :its pretty simple if you try..make sure you try something before you post any question next time..

Comment: This is not as simple as you are thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about this for the past few days and basically I can't think of a single use case for what you're doing that wouldn't be better solved by implementing a simple sprite sheet solution. You could also acquire any of the hundreds of available solutions out there that implement sheet-based solutions to this problem.

Loading a texture is not a trivial task for the engine and whenever possible you want to limit your inode access. Using a single Atlas texture that has all of your sub-images placed at regular intervals would be one easy solution. You would then iterate over the map and assign mainTextureOffsets for each material that uses the same image. You can also use irregular placement but for that you'll need some kind of transient medium to store the offset values.

Rather than storing the texture2d in memory in this solution; you will instead be storing Vector2 structs which are far less memory intense. If you have a use case that falls outside the parameters of what you can do with sprite sheets (Atlas maps) you'll have to detail it fully here so we can help you further but I'm fairly certain this will get you to a solution in the most efficacious manner.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I have updated my question, i have done that task temporarily , but i want to know a better way to doing this.

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshjain24/ZaLtL/)

```
var outer_array = [];
 var inner_array = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
     inner_array.push(i);
     if (inner_array.length == 4) {
         outer_array.push(inner_array);//push the array[0,1,2,3] and so on in to outer array.
         inner_array = [];//this will empty my array
         i = i + 6;//to jump from 4 to 10,14 to 20 and so on..
     }
 }

 console.log(outer_array)
```

Comment: You need to be more explicit with the issues you are having.

Comment: Beacuse i need to store **textures** that is type of Texture2d in unity. for that i need to create the array of textures.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to do this.
Declare a 2d array and set row and column to 100 and use below lines of code.
noOfPattern and noOfColors are integers to get the count of row and columns of 2d array.

```
var arrAll = new Texture2D[100,100];

for(var p=0 ; p<100 ; p++){

TextureP = Resources.Load("FolderName/"+"ImageName"+p+0);
if(TextureP !=null){
for(var q=0 ; q<100 ; q++){
TextureQ = Resources.Load("FolderName/"+"ImageName"+p+q);
if(TextureQ !=null){
arrAll[p,q] = TextureQ;
noOfColors = q;
}
}
noOfPattern = p;
}
}
```